# How can I do calculations with previous defined columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently trying to calculate a column using previous declared columns. I think that would work in MySQL, but I'm unsure how do do that in PostgreSQL.

My Statement looks like this:

```
SELECT customerNumber, customerName, (
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(payments.amount), 0)
    FROM payments
    WHERE customers.customerNumber = payments.customerNumber
  ) as totalOfPaymentsMade,(
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(orderdetails.priceeach * orderdetails.quantityordered), 0)
    FROM orders
    LEFT JOIN orderdetails ON orderdetails.ordernumber = orders.ordernumber
    WHERE customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
  ) as totalValueOfAllOrdersMade, creditLimit, creditLimit + totalOfPaymentsMade - totalValueOfAllOrdersMade as amountOfAvailableCredit
FROM customers
ORDER BY customerNumber
```

I get this error message: `column "totalofpaymentsmade" does not exist
LINE 11: ...lValueOfAllOrdersMade, creditLimit, creditLimit + totalOfPay...`

Comment: don't you miss the GROUP BY statements for SUMs ?

Comment: I think I don't need a GROUP BY statement at this point, since I'm using subquerys and want to SUM all rows that match my WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   *,
   creditLimit + totalOfPaymentsMade - totalValueOfAllOrdersMade 
   as amountOfAvailableCredit
from
(

SELECT 
    customerNumber, 
    customerName, 
    creditLimit,

    (
      SELECT COALESCE(SUM(payments.amount), 0)
      FROM payments
      WHERE customers.customerNumber = payments.customerNumber
    ) 
    as totalOfPaymentsMade,

    (
      SELECT COALESCE(SUM(orderdetails.priceeach * orderdetails.quantityordered), 0)
      FROM orders
      LEFT JOIN orderdetails ON orderdetails.ordernumber = orders.ordernumber
      WHERE customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
    ) 
    as totalValueOfAllOrdersMade 

FROM customers

) a

ORDER BY customerNumber
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved me some hours!